# Как получить url картинки из rss ленты?

Tags: xml, android, sax, парсер, rss

Как получить url картинки для дальнейшей обработки? Парсю ленту (xml sax parser). В ленте есть тег `<description>`, в нем лежит картинка вида:

```
<div style="text-align: center"><img src="http://gazetaingush.ru/images/stories/2014/161/161-1.gif" border="1" hspace="5" vspace="5" width="450" height="300" /></div><div style="text-align: center">
```

Как ее вытащить и загрузить в layout post?

**Обновление**

```
item.getChild("link").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
    public void end(String body) {
        currentPost.setLink(body);
    }
});
item.getChild("description").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
    public void end(String body) {
        currentPost.setDescription(body);
    }
});
```

Вот кусок кода из парсера где мы получаем сам <description> в нутри него картинка

Вот класc postItem

```
public class PostItem {
    static SimpleDateFormat FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US);
  //  static SimpleDateFormat OUT_FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MMM.yyyy HH:mm");
    private String title; // Название поста
    private URL link; // Ссылка на пост на сайте (в формате URL для использования в Java)
    private String linkText; // Ссылка на пост на сайте (в виде строки текста для вывода)
    private String description; // Описание поста
    private Date date; // Дата публикации поста (в формате Date для обработки в программе)

/**
     * Setter для title    
     * @param title
     */
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title.trim();
    }
    /**
     * Getter для title
     * @return
     */
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }  
    /**
     * Setter для description
     * @param description
     */
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description.trim();
    }
```

Comment: не знаю точно, как работает sax, но это же очевидно, что взять у вашего элемента первый дочерний, и у дочернего взять атрибут src. И что такое layout post?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы использовал  `.//img[1]/@src`, но я пользуюсь другим инструментом.

Comment: можно попподробнее весь интернет перерыл не могу найти ответ 
сам парсер писал вот по этому примеру 
http://anddev.ru/30/prostoy-rss-parser-dlya-sayta.html

помогите пожалуйста